# Dynamic JQUERY not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

```
<?php
include("dbFunctions.php");
$query ="SELECT * FROM medical_category";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
//datebase query
?>
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Official form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/jquery-ui.css" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-    1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 //javascript
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>

// tabs function

</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">

   <?php while ($arrayResult = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>

  // fetch the array , is the vertical data affecting the alignment of tabs

    <li><a href="#tabs-<?php echo $arrayResult['Medical_category_id']?> "><? php echo $arrayResult['Medical_categoryName']; ?></a></li>
```

the php part is working but the tabs based on the id  is not aligning well
    
    
my echo data is currently vertically aligned
how to make the tabs work again?
the data are also separated by bullets , it is not aligned as a tab suppose to be

Comment: `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-    1.10.2.min.js"></script>`, spaces in src??

Comment: Check your console for errors

Comment: i figured out now , forgotten to include <ul> </ul>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
include("dbFunctions.php");
$query ="SELECT * FROM medical_category";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
?>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Official form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $('#tabs li>div').appendTo('#tabs');
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <?php while ($arrayResult = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
    <li><a href="#tabs-<?php echo $arrayResult['Medical_category_id']?>"><?php echo $arrayResult['Medical_categoryName']; ?></a>
    <div id="tabs-<?php echo $arrayResult['Medical_category_id']?>"><p>content of the tab</p></div></li>
    <?php };?>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know that the OP accepted this after they posted the comment about the problem, but why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I'll remember this for future answers.